# Hover Style overridden by selected style in html table row

Tags: javascript, html, dhtml

I have a simple html table which has several rows. the following is implemented

1) I have given style for mouseover event of the row so that it will be highlighted once the mouse moves over it.

2)Each row has a checkbox as well. once this is selected, the row which the check box is in need to be shown in a different color as well.

The problem is that, once the row background changes after clicking the checkbox, the hover style applied to the onmoseover event of the row no longer applies.

Following is the code;

```
<html>
<head></head>

<style type="text/css">
  tr { background: blue; }
  tr:hover { background:green; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

function Highlight(row)
{       
    if(document.getElementById('chk').checked)
    {
        document.getElementById(row).style.background='Red';
    }
    else
    {                   
        document.getElementById(row).onMouseOver = function() { this.className = 'hover'; }                 
    }       
}

</script>

<body>

<table>
<tr><th>Name</th> <th>Age</th></tr>

<tr id="row1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" onMouseOver="className='hover';">
<td><input type="checkbox" id="chk" onclick="javascript:Highlight('row1');"</td>

<td>25</td></tr>
<tr id="row2"><td>aaaaaa</td><td>25</td></tr>
<tr id="row3"><td>aaaaaa</td><td>25</td></tr>

</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Appreciate if you could give me a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want,

CSS - option I

```
 .yellow{ background:yellow; }
```

Javascript - Option I

```
   function Highlight(row)
{       
    if(document.getElementById('chk').checked)
    {
        document.getElementById(row).className += " yellow"document.getElementById(row).style.background='Red';
    }
    else
    {    
        document.getElementById(row).className = document.getElementById(row).className.replace(/\byellow\b/,'')
    }

    document.getElementById(row).removeAttribute("style");
        document.getElementById(row).onMouseOver = function() { this.className += 'hover';                    

    hover'; }                 
    }       
}
```

Javascript - Option II

```
 function Highlight(row)
{       
    if(document.getElementById('chk').checked)
    {
        document.getElementById(row).style.background='Red';
    }
    else
    {    
        document.getElementById(row).removeAttribute("style");
        document.getElementById(row).onMouseOver = function() { this.className = 'hover'; }                 
    }       
}
```

HTML

```
<tr id="row1">
```

Answer (score 2):

It's doing what you are telling it to do, right here:

```
if(document.getElementById('chk').checked)
{
    document.getElementById(row).style.background='Red';
}
else
{
    document.getElementById(row).onMouseOver = function() { this.className = 'hover'; }
}
```

You're saying, if it's checked, then it's red. If it's not, then it's `hover`-able.

To fix would look something like this:

CSS:

```
.hover { background:blue }
.hover:hover { background:green }
.hoverChecked { background:red }
.hoverChecked:hover { background:green }
```

JS:

```
if(document.getElementById('chk').checked) {
  document.getElementById(row).className = 'hoverChecked';
}
else {
  document.getElementById(row).className = 'hover'; 
}
```

You also may want to fix your HTML:

```
<tr id="row1" style='background:#FFFFFF' class='hover'>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because of your if..else:

```
function Highlight(row)
{       
    if(document.getElementById('chk').checked)
    {
        document.getElementById(row).style.background='Red';
    }           
}
```

You shouldn't need your else paths at all. Css will apply your :hover styles automatically.

Comment: Sorry, i couldn't mention previously, the hover style should apply only after the check box is unchecked. but still, removing the else part did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Ie8-9 compatibility?

```
document.getElementById(row).onMouseOver = function() { this.className = 'hover'; }
```

Does not work ie9.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!
Put on html this line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
```